# Binding in Combobox in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox, styles

I'm a beginner in wpf. Actually I'm styling a `ComboBox` which receives data from a database. 
The `ComboBox` works fine at this point without a style.

I have edited the `ControlTemplate` of the `ComboboxItem` control in a stylesheet, like a resource dictionary.

If the `Style` applies to `ComboBox` with static data, the style works fine.  But if the style applies to `ComboBox` with dynamic data (binding from a database in this case), the items list only returns the object (the items shown is similar to "Class.Method.Property") but not the content of the property that I need to show.

I have been trying all, and I have read everything on the internet about xaml styles and `ComboBox` templates but I couldn't solve the problem.

My `ContentPresenter` looks like this which returns the object of the databinding:

```
<ContentPresenter
        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentTemplate}"
        Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}"/>
```

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 4):

"Class.Method.Property" is shown because WPF doesn't know how to do display your class. What you need is a DataTemplate for your class.

Unless you really need it, I wouldn't dig so deep in to the templates as you have in your examples.

If you have a databound ComboBox with objects and you just want to display a property of the bound object you can do:

```
 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="FullName" />
```

If you want a more advanced display, you can set the ItemTemplate.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Person}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 4):

I recently ran into the same issue and to fix it my content presenter now looks like this:

```
<ContentPresenter                            
    Content="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.SelectionBoxItem}"
    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
    ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" />
```

My problem, much like yours, was the fact that I was missing the ContentTemplateSelector. Also if you are having issue with the drop down showing incorrectly as well, I found that in the ComboBoxItem style you can leave the content presenter blank (`<ContentPresenter />`) and it will display properly.